# JQuery DataTables not work method Draw ();

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Trying to redraw the table. 
It is necessary to redraw the table when you click on the icon. No errors but the table is updated at the second click on the removal icon.

What is the problem?`

```
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery');
var dataTable = require('../bower/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js');
$.DataTable = dataTable;

var App = {
  InitUsertable: null, //Table of users
  mestype: null,
  init: function () {
  this._initHandler();
    console.log('init dTable');
    this._initDtDefaultSettings();
    this.InitUserTable();
    this.InitProductTable();
    this.InitCostTable();
    this.InitMestypeTable();

  },
  _initHandler: function () {

    $(document).on('click', '#delete', this.InitButtons.bind(this));

  },
  _initDtDefaultSettings: function () {
    $.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
      "lengthMenu": [10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 200],
      "oLanguage": {
        "sProcessing": false,
        "sLengthMenu": "Показывать  _MENU_  строк",
        "sZeroRecords": "Ничего не найдено",
        "sInfo": "Показано с _START_ по _END_ из _TOTAL_ строк",
        "sInfoEmtpy": "Показано с 0 по 0 из 0 строк",
        "sInfoFiltered": "(выбрано из _MAX_)",
        "sInfoPostFix": "",
        "sSearch": "Поиск: ",
        "sUrl": "",
        "sEmptyTable": "Ничего не найдено",
        "oPaginate": {"sFirst": "First", "sLast": "Last", "sNext": "Следующая", "sPrevious": "Предыдущая"},
        "sInfoEmpty": "Показано с 0 по 0 из 0 строк",
        "sLoadingRecords": "loading..."
      },
      "serverSide": true,  
      "bProcessing": false,  
      "bDeferRender": true, 
      "bAutoWidth": false,
      "bFilter": true,  
      "bInfo": true,  
      "bSortClasses": true, 
      "bStateSave": true
    })
  },



  InitMestypeTable: function () {
    if ($('#mestypeTable').length != 0) {
      var _this = this;
      var urlAll = 'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/mestype';
      _this.mestypeTable = $('#mestypeTable').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {url: urlAll, type: 'GET'},
        "order": [[0, "desc"]],
        "columns": [
          {data: "id", "orderable": false, render:
                    function (data, type, row)
                    {
                      return  data;

                    }},
          {data: "name", "orderable": false, render:
                    function (data, type, row)
                    {
                      return  data;

                    }
          },
          {data: "short_name", "orderable": false, render:
                    function (data, type, row)
                    {

                      return  data;
                    }
          },
          {data: "edit", "orderable": false, render:
                    function (data, type, row)
                    {
                      return  '<a href="/admin/edit-mestype?id=' + data + '" data-toggle="ajaxModal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>';
                    }
          },
          {data: "delete", "orderable": false, render:
                    function (data, type, row)
                    {
                      return  '<a href="/mestypes/' + data + '" data-method= "delete" id="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>';
                    }
          },
        ],
      });
    }
    ;
  },
  InitButtons: function () {

    App.mestypeTable.draw();

  },
};
module.exports = App;
```

`

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$('#mestypeTable').ajax.reload( null, false );
```